# Retrieve JSON data in android?

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to retrieve the JSON data from the server in my android app. JSON file consist of question along with 4 choices. I am trying to retrieve the question and the 4 choices individually and set to list view in android to display like multiple choice question. Android throught the response but I could not get individual data. Below is my code.

*file.json*

```
 {"multiple":[{
"question": "In which course are you inrolled in?",
"choice 1":"BIM",
"choice 2":"BBA",
"choice 3":"BIT",
"choice 4":"BSCCSIT"
},
{
"question": "What comes after n?",
"choice 1":"s",
"choice 2":"t",
"choice 3":"o",
"choice 4":"p"
}
]
}
```

*sending.php*

```
<?php

    header('Content-type:application/json');

$data =file_get_contents('/var/www/html/file.json');

$row =json_encode($data);

echo ($row);
?>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
package com.multiple;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.*;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;



public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    private ListView listview;
    List<HashMap<String,String>> collect= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        populate p = new populate();
        p.execute();
    }

    public class populate extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
        {
            public Void doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
                    try
                    {

                        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpGet post = new HttpGet("http://192.168.10.120/sending.php");
                        HttpResponse res= client.execute(post);
                        HttpEntity entity = res.getEntity();

                        String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                        Log.i("response",response);



                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);


                        JSONArray jsonArray = obj.optJSONArray("multiple");

                        for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = jsonObject.optString("question").toString();
                            String name = jsonObject.optString("choice1").toString();
                            String salary =jsonObject.optString("choice2").toString();
                            String ssalary =jsonObject.optString("choice3").toString();
                            String sssalary =jsonObject.optString("choice4").toString();

                            Log.i("qq",id);
                            Log.i("asdfas",salary);
                            Log.i("asjdfha",name);
                            Log.i("asdfas",salary);
                        }

//                      String questions = obj.optString("question").toString();
//                      String choices=obj.optString("answers").toString();
                    }

                    catch(IOException ex){}

                    catch(JSONException ex){}

                return  null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }

        }

        String[] str = new String[]{"first","second","third","fourth","fifth"};
        int[] val = new int[]{R.id.textView1,R.id.checkBox1,R.id.checkBox2,R.id.checkBox3,R.id.checkBox4};
}
```

How could I retrieve the JSON data separately?/

Comment: is your json file correct? try to wrap it into `{` here yor content `}`

Comment: Add your data or `Strings` in your `listview` and display using `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: what do you have in  `Log.i("response",response);`?

Comment: "{\"multiple\":[{\n\"question\": \"In which course are you inrolled in?\",\n\"choice 1\":\"BIM\",\n\"choice 2\":\"BBA\",\n\"choice 3\":\"BIT\",\n\"choice 4\":\"BSCCSIT\"\n},\n{\n\"question\": \"What comes after n?\",\n\"choice 1\":\"s\",\n\"choice 2\":\"t\",\n\"choice 3\":\"o\",\n\"choice 4\":\"p\"\n}\n]\n}\n"

Answer (score 0):

use   ArrayList>()

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arr_list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

arr_list.clear();
//create and clear your array

and

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);


                    JSONArray jsonArray = obj.optJSONArray("multiple");
        int count=1;
                    for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String id=String.valueOf(count);
                        String ques = jsonObject.optString("question").toString();
                        String c1= jsonObject.optString("choice1").toString();
                        String c2=jsonObject.optString("choice2").toString();
                        String c3=jsonObject.optString("choice3").toString();
                        String c4=jsonObject.optString("choice4").toString();


                   addToArray(id,ques,c1,c2,c3,c4);
                     count++;
                    }
```

then..

Comment: private void addToArray(String id,String ques,String c1,String c2,String c3,String c4)
{
   HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
 map.put("id", id);
 map.put("ques", ques);
 map.put("c1",c1);
 map.put("c2", c2);
 map.put("c3", c3);
 map.put("c4", c4);
    
 arr_list.add(map);

Log.d("value","arr="+arr_list);

}

Comment: When I write :
tring size = String.valueOf(jsonArray.length());
      Log.i("size",size);
nothing is displayed in LOGCAT. So I guessed  JSONArray jsonArray = obj.optJSONArray("multiple"); isnot storing any value.

Comment: change to JSONArray jsonArray=obj.getJSONArray("multiple"); and check

Comment: I am sorry but it didnot help

Answer (score 0):

You need to retain values in a `Collection`, `ArrayList` of `JSONObject` will be handy in this situation:

```
for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    arrListJsonObject.add(jsonObject); 

    /* String id = jsonObject.optString("question").toString();
    String name = jsonObject.optString("choice1").toString();
    String salary =jsonObject.optString("choice2").toString();
    String ssalary =jsonObject.optString("choice3").toString();
    String sssalary =jsonObject.optString("choice4").toString();

    Log.i("qq",id);
    Log.i("asdfas",salary);
    Log.i("asjdfha",name);
    Log.i("asdfas",salary); */
}
```

Here **arrListJsonObject** is `ArrayList<JSONObject>`. 
Now you can use :

```
for(int i=0;i<arrListJsonObject.size();i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject = arrListJsonObject.get(i); // or arrListJsonObject.get(position) inside getView method of a custom Adapter.
    String question = jsonObject.optString("question").toString();
    String c1 = jsonObject.optString("choice1").toString();
    String c2 = jsonObject.optString("choice2").toString();
    String c3 = jsonObject.optString("choice3").toString();
    String c4 = jsonObject.optString("choice4").toString();

   // Now you have question and choices as question, c1, c2, c3, c4 respectively.
}
```

Hope that Helps!!!

Comment: I am sorry but it doesnot help. I think this  JSONArray jsonArray = obj.optJSONArray("multiple") is not working because when i try to display the size of the jsonArray in Logcat nothing is displaye

Comment: @programmingtech Have you used `printStackTrace()` in the catch block?

Comment: Thank you it helped me. Actually I directly passed the json file in HttpPost instead of passing php file

Comment: programmingtech You're welcome, you can appreciate the answer if you want to. Well, Thank you anyways.